# how to automate autocomplete tags in selenium ide?

Tags: selenium-ide

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>css=ul.token-input-list-facebook</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>setCursorPosition</td>
    <td>id=token-input-SongTags</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=token-input-SongTags</td>
    <td>n</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>setCursorPosition</td>
    <td>id=token-input-SongTags</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=token-input-SongTags</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I tried out the above steps to automate autocomplete tags, but this is not working,

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>css=(first click)</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=(second click)</td>
    <td>${tagname}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>typeKeys</td>
    <td>id=(second click)</td>
    <td>${tagname}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>focus</td>
    <td>id=(second click)</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>keyDown</td>
    <td>id=(second click)</td>
    <td>\40</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>keyDown</td>
    <td>id=(second click)</td>
    <td>\40</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>keyDown</td>
    <td>id=(second click)</td>
    <td>\13</td>
</tr>
```